# Angular : For Exponent `e`, What is best way to handle Dirty function checking in `(KeyDown)` event?

Tags: angular

I have a input field `<input type="number" (keydown)="onKeydown($event)">` 
In angular when we defined `type=number` then it not allow to any character expected `e`.
My problem is avoid `e` character from these field.
These `onKeydown` function i have check `keyCode` and its work fine and it avoid `e`,
But when i press any keyboard key then that time function is called.
I want to call function when only i press `e` key.

My function is

```
onKeydown(event) {
    // here call every keypress 
    console.log(event);
    return event.keyCode !== 69;
}
```

How to handle it?

Comment: So how you want to call your function? when field loses it's focus?

Comment: I didn't understand what's a dirty checking

Comment: I am asking you that how you want to call your function? Do you want that your function shuld call when user leaves a input box ?

Comment: @bhagwat tupe how you want to call your onKeydown functions i mean do you want to call function for integer value or characters?

Comment: Hi, i have edit my question please check

Comment: it's still unclear that at what stage you want to call your function?

Comment: Hi @Fashad I want to call function when only when i press `e` key

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this

If you want to call the onKeydown function on e key then check the condition

```
<input type="text" (keydown.e)="onKeydown($event)">
```

I have created stackblitz link here [Click here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ksuhdx)

I hope this will be useful

Answer (score 0):

You can use keyup control options like this

in .component.html

```
(keydown)="onKeydown($event)
```

in component.ts

```
onKeydown(){
 if(event.keyCode == 69){
    // call your main function which you want to call on press of 'e' key
  }
}
```

Through this your function will call when you press `e` key only

Answer (score 0):

You can create the directive and you can use it in all the input elements across the app. From your code I assume that you don't want allow user to press "e" key.
So, I have created 1 stackblitz demo by creating the a directive which can detect the keypress event.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-axdksw